# nest.js фильтрация данных

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

у nest.js есть такой метод

```
repositoty.find(/*тут FindConditions*/);
```

так вот например есть условия фильтрации

```
{a: 'value', b: 2020, c: -1}
```

Выбрать те данные которые у которых поля a, b, c совпадают с полями из объекта

Как это правильно сделать подскажите

или напрмер можно ли сделать так

```
repositoty.find({}).filter(x => /*тут условия*/)
```

будет ли филтрация сделана на уже выполненный запрос в базу или это трансформируется в запроc;

Comment: repositoty.find({where: {a: 'value', b: 2020, c: -1}}) - фильтрация будет на уровне запроса к бд